# Need to read secure cookie and need to check if it exists or not

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to access secure cookie and based on its existence, i need to do some url redirection of the code.

I tried doing below but it seems secure cookies is not readable. Can you please let me know if there is any other way doing it.

Below code always going in a else block even if I can see the cookie[image: highlighted cookie is secure and need to read this cookie in jsp/java] in my browser.

```
 $(function() {

var name='DCCCtxCookie';
  var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
  if (match) {
    console.log("DCCCtxCookie found : "+match);
  }
  else{
     console.log('--something went wrong---');
     window.location.replace("https://google.com"); 
  }
});
```

Below are the cookies shows up in console log.

[image: document.cookies]

Comment: So what does the raw output of `document.cookie` look like? That regex definitely looks fishy.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Document.cookie is provide other cookies values but this DCCCtxCookie is not there